# Signing transactions can not find private key

Tags: blockchain, wallet

Please I need help. I have made an transaction online using bitcoin, but the order cancelled and now my bitcoins are stuck. I've been using coinb.in the first time a while ago and was able to do it successfully. Now the private key is not letting me pass the same one I used last time. What can I do to get back my bitcoins?

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Electrum wallet since.
I'm trying to explain my situation better.

So this is where it starts this is my cancelled order. I've redacted parts of them, but you hopefully get the idea.
My order site has refund information as you can see from the picture. So what I did last time was using coinb.in and it worked. I copy this
code of numbers given to coinb.in.
https://postimg.cc/34wht4xM

Coinb.in recognizes the transaction. The address I used with my Electrum wallet is there.
https://postimg.cc/grq5xkz8

The next step is to sign the transaction with my private key. I remembered I have a file saved on my computer with my private key information. I have saved my private key and all PGP key password information on my computer and been using this the last 3-4 years. So I opened it and used the private key to which it wasn't recognized.

This is my saved private key information.
https://postimg.cc/bG9Csm88

Previously on the vendors website I'd save my bitcoin refund address and public key. The public key matches, but the address is different, because the new Electrum I updated in the past changes my Electrum receive address.
https://postimg.cc/62DYPgfr

Anyway, when I enter the private key from my saved note the following occurs:
https://postimg.cc/627MYtn6

So then what I did was I looked up all my addresses on my Electrum wallet and I found the one I did the transaction and it has the private key next to it like in the picture here:
https://postimg.cc/3kK9zgmc

I typed in this private key, but I still can't verify:
https://postimg.cc/627MYtn6

So my bitcoins are stuck now and I don't know what to do how to get them back IF.....

I hope I've explained myself better. What do you think I should do now?

Answer (score 0):

Try copying the transaction into electrum and see if you can sign & broadcast it there yourself.

It's under Tools -> Load transaction -> From text. It opens a new window where you can paste the transaction. If electrum has the correct private key available, it will offer you the options to sign & broadcast the transaction.

Ideally always avoid sending your private keys to third parties.